# Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'

Tags: python

When running the following code, I get the error `"Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'"` . Even after researching similar questions, I cannot solve this problem, so I would greatly appreciate any help! Here is the section of code I'm having trouble with:

```
 r = 1
    def simpson_2var(a,b,f,N,z2):         
        h = (b-a) / (N)
        s = f(a, z2) + f(b, z2)
        for i in range(1,N):
            if(i%2 ==0):
                s += 2*(f(a + i*h, z2))
            else:
                s += 4*(f(a + i*h, z2))
        s *= (h/3.0) 
        return s
    z2 = np.linspace(-10,10,1000,0)


 def f(R,z2):
    return (R * z2) / ( ( z2**2 + R**2) ** (3/2))
E2 = simpson_2var(0,1,f,1000,z2)
    r = 1

    z3 = np.linspace(-4*r, 4*r, 1000, 0)

    w = simpson_2var(f,0, r, 1000, z3)

    plt.plot(w, z3, label = "R=1", color = "cyan")

    plt.legend()

    plt.xlabel("Electric Field")

    plt.ylabel("distance to zz axis'")

    plt.grid()

    plt.show()
```

This is the error I get (here I left the comments for line numbering reasons):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-3bfacd988809> in <module>
      1 r = 1
      2 z3 = np.linspace(-4*r, 4*r, 1000, 0)
----> 3 w = simpson_2var(f,0, r, 1000, z3)
      4 plt.plot(w, z3, label = "R=1", color = "cyan")
      5 plt.legend()

<ipython-input-42-7c0c9c6d708d> in simpson_2var(a, b, f, N, z2)
      4                                     # de 1. Usamos esta função logo neste exercício, para função com
      5                                     # variáveis R e z2
----> 6     h = (b-a) / (N)
      7     s = f(a, z2) + f(b, z2)
      8     for i in range(1,N):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'
```

Once more, I'd really appreciate any help provided. Thank you.

Comment: you've defined `f` to be a function somewhere or assigned `f` to a function, check your code

Comment: `a` is a function. You can't the function `a` from integer `b`. `a` here is the first argument to `simpson_2var()`, so `f`, which you didn't share.

Comment: I have edited the code section to include the f function. I didn't include it at first because I didn't think it would be relevant, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arguments do not seem to correspond between `w = simpson_2var(f,0, r, 1000, z3)` and `def simpson_2var(a,b,f,N,z2)`.

Try using named arguments when calling functions:

`w = simpson_2var(a=0, b=r, f=f, N=1000, z2=z3)`

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark this answer as the solution if you're satisfied with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You error comes from the line `h = (b-a) / (N)`, where `b=0` but `a` is a function, not a value. So, fix the function call in

```
w = simpson_2var(f,0, r, 1000, z3)
```